# How to disentangle child and parent __init__ methods in Python?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am trying to find the right way to use inheritance when the order for the attributes being set for the parent class will break in the child class. Here's an example:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, efficiency, tank_size) -> None:
        self.efficiency = efficiency
        self.tank_size = tank_size
        self.range = self.calc_range()

    def calc_range(self):
        return self.efficiency * self.tank_size


class HybridCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, efficiency, tank_size, battery_capacity) -> None:
        super().__init__(efficiency, tank_size)
        self.battery_range = self.calc_battery_range()
        self.battery_capacity = battery_capacity

    def calc_range(self):
        return self.efficiency * self.tank_size + self.battery_range

    def calc_battery_range(self):
        return self.battery_capacity * self.efficiency
```

I would like `HybridCar` to call `Car`'s `__init__` method but I can't get it to work. I can't call `self.calc_range()` in `HybridCar` because I don't have `self.battery_range` defined. And I can't define `self.battery_range` because that relies on `self.efficiency`, which I haven't defined yet. The only way I can see to make this work is for HybridCar not to call `Car`'s `__init__` method but instead have all the same code. I want to avoid this because there's a lot of code in the `__init__` method (the real class does much more than this) and seems like bad practice to have lots of duplicated code (And pylint warns me about not calling `super().__init__`). What's the right way to solve this?

Comment: Maybe set once efficiency in the beginning of hybrid car init. It's a bit ugly but already better than copying all of car init.

Comment: This kind of thing is why calling overridable methods in a constructor is a bad idea.

Comment: I thought that was OK in Python... is it not? Isn't that what they're saying here or am I misinterpreting it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6859112/2514130

Comment: That answerer is interpreting "this does not inherently raise an exception" as "this is safe". Calling an overridden method in a superclass constructor is a recipe for horrible circular dependency issues (like what you're seeing now), even if the mere attempt to do so does not raise an exception on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like the following help you?

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, efficiency, tank_size) -> None:
        self.efficiency = efficiency
        self.tank_size = tank_size
        self.range = self.calc_range_Car()

    def calc_range_Car(self):
        return self.efficiency * self.tank_size


class HybridCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, battery_capacity, car) -> None:
        super().__init__(car.efficiency, car.tank_size)
        self.battery_capacity = battery_capacity
        self.battery_range = self.calc_battery_range()

    def calc_range_Hybrid(self):
        return self.efficiency * self.tank_size + self.battery_range

    def calc_battery_range(self):
        return self.battery_capacity * self.efficiency

parent = Car(2, 5)
child = HybridCar(10, parent)
print(child.calc_range_Car())
print(parent.range)
```

The only thing I do differently is that I a `Car` object to the `HybridCar` constructor as well as renaming the method `calc_range` to `calc_range_Car` and `calc_range_Hybrid`. I understand that this might not be ideal because overriding superclass method in the subclass is really useful.
**Output**

```
10
10
```

Comment: This works because `calc_range` is simple enough that you can essentially remove it and do find `self.range` directly. In my real case, there's a lot more going on so it wouldn't work as well. I was struggling to find a way to ask the question with a minimal example that still contained everything important, but seems like I didn't do that perfectly.

Comment: Is it possible to post your whole script and expected output? I will try modify my answer according to your needs

Comment: It adds way more complexity than it's worth. I think the fundamental problem I'm dealing with is here, I just need a more scalable solution.

Comment: The answer is updated. Does this work for you or do you need your superclass function to override the subclass function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) definition in your class. This means that your assignment of `self.range = self.calc_range()` function won't actually be executed during the `__init__()`. But instead `self.calc_range()` will be run each time you are trying to get the `range` property.

You also mentioned that there is a lot of potential duplicate code, so in the example below I've included the use of the [`abc` (Abstract Base Class)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABC) concept. Which is a pretty handy concept when you have inherited classes that share methods with the same name, but have different implementations.

```py
import abc


class CarABC(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self, efficiency, tank_size) -> None:
        self.efficiency = efficiency
        self.tank_size = tank_size

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def calc_range(self):
        pass

    @property
    def range(self):
        return self.calc_range()


class Car(CarABC):
    def calc_range(self):
        return self.efficiency * self.tank_size


class HybridCar(CarABC):
    def __init__(self, efficiency, tank_size, battery_capacity) -> None:
        super().__init__(efficiency, tank_size)
        self.battery_capacity = battery_capacity

    @property
    def battery_range(self):
        return self.calc_battery_range()

    def calc_range(self):
        return self.efficiency * self.tank_size + self.battery_range

    def calc_battery_range(self):
        return self.battery_capacity * self.efficiency

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Car(0.8, 100)
    hc = HybridCar(0.8, 100, 120)
    print(c.range)
```