# Calling overriden method from the constructor. What to use instead?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor

I have a code in Java, where I should call the overriden method from the constructor of base class. 
I understand that it may cause problems according to many references for example:

[Calling an overridden method from a parent class ctor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898422/calling-an-overridden-method-from-a-parent-class-ctor)

and also

https://medium.com/@rufuszh90/effective-java-item-17-design-and-document-for-inheritance-or-else-prohibit-it-be6041719fbc

The question I have which pattern to use instead?

---

Adding sample code here is a Task constructor:

```
 public <T extends AbstractCommon & IParent> Task(T parent, String uuid, String version, Set<AbstractNode> exceptions) throws Exception {
    Event tef = getExecutionFinishedEvent();
    Event tep = getExecutionInProgressEvent();
    Event tefailed = getExecutionFailed();
    Event tefinishedonallnodes = getExecutionFinishedOnAllNodesEvent();
    Event tTimeout = getTimeoutEvent();
    Event tNotAllNodesAreAcessible = getNotAllNodesAreAccessible();
    Event tNotAllObjectsAreAvailable = getNotAllObjectsAreAvailable();

}
```

Here is the extending class AbstractRemoteTask  and there are some others.

```
public abstract class AbstractRemoteTask extends Task implements InterNodeProcessor {

public AbstractRemoteTask() {
}

@JsonIgnore
@Override
protected Event getExecutionFinishedEvent() {
    return getEvent(Event.EventType.EXECUTION_FINISHED_LOCAL);
}

@JsonIgnore
@Override
protected Event getExecutionFinishedOnAllNodesEvent() {
    return getEvent(Event.EventType.EXECUTION_FINISHED_ON_ALL_NODES);
}

@Override
protected Event getExecutionInProgressEvent() {
    return getEvent(Event.EventType.EXECUTION_IN_PROGRESS);
}

@JsonIgnore
@Override
protected Event getExecutionFailed() {
    return getEvent(Event.EventType.EXECUTION_FAILED);
}


@JsonIgnore
@Override
protected Event getTimeoutEvent() {
    return new RemoteEvent(this, getNodeUuid(), Event.EventType.TIMEOUT);
}

@JsonIgnore
@Override
protected Event getNotAllNodesAreAccessible() {
    return new RemoteEvent(this, getNodeUuid(), Event.EventType.NOT_ALL_NODES_ARE_ACCESSIBLE);
}

@JsonIgnore
@Override
protected Event getNotAllObjectsAreAvailable() {
    return new RemoteEvent(this, getNodeUuid(), Event.EventType.NOT_ALL_OBJECTS_ARE_AVAILABLE);
}
```

So the question is what is the best pattern to implement this? As the way it is implemented is not recommended.

Comment: A separate initialisation method that is called *after* the constructor is called.

Comment: It would be more helpful for us if you could show us the code and what you want to do.